# why is my isEmpty and isFull function not working?

Tags: c++

I have implemented stack in this code.
When I use option 6 the do-while loop runs again and when I use option 7 switch case uses the default case for some reason.
What is the error here?
I also tried to remove the do-while loop but it didn't solve anything.
Is there a problem with the object or are the functions wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
class Stack{
private:
    int top;
    int arr[5];

public:
    Stack(){
        top = -1;
        for(int i;i<5;i++){
            arr[i]=0;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        if(top==-1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool isFull(){
        if(top==4){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    void push(int num){
        if(isFull()){
                cout<<"Stack Overflow";
        }
        else{
            top++;
            arr[top] = num;
            cout<<"The number pushed is:"<<num;
        }
    }

    int pop(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            cout<<"Stack Underflow";
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int popval = arr[top];
            arr[top] = 0;
            top--;
            return popval;
        }
    }

    int peek(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            cout<<"Stack Empty";
        }
        else{
            return arr[top];
        }
    }

    int count(){
       

        return(top+1);
      
        }


    void change(int pos,int num){
        arr[pos] = num;
    }

    void display(){
        for(int i=top;i>=0;i--){
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    Stack s1;
    int option;
    int tempnum,position;
    do{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"MAIN MENU"<<endl;
    cout<<"1) Push"<<endl;
    cout<<"2) Pop"<<endl;
    cout<<"3) Peek"<<endl;
    cout<<"4) Display"<<endl;
    cout<<"5) Count"<<endl;
    cout<<"6) Check Empty"<<endl;
    cout<<"7) Check Full"<<endl;
    cout<<"8) Exit"<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter your choice:";
    cin>>option;

    switch(option){
    case 1:
        cout<<"Enter the number:";
        cin>>tempnum;
        s1.push(tempnum);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"The popped number is "<<s1.pop()<<endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"Element at top is"<<s1.peek()<<endl;
    case 4:
        s1.display();
    case 5:
        cout<<"Number of elements is:"<<s1.count();
    case 6:
        if(s1.isEmpty()==true){
            cout<<"Stack Empty";
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        if(s1.isFull()==true){
            cout<<"Stack Full";
        }
    default:
        cout<<"Enter Valid Option";
    }
    }while(option!=0);
}
```

Comment: `int i;` doesn't initialize `i`. It will have an *indeterminate* value, and using it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you have `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` that's the exact same thing as `return condition;`.

Comment: Please enable your compiler warnings. [My compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0HdZ2v5dcHvX0zOA) immediately told me that you are missing some `break` statements after `case`s.

Comment: Each `case` in `switch` falls through to all code below, even if that code is for other `case`s. You have to use `break` to ensure it stops processing within the `switch` block. This is for instance missing for cases 3, 4, 5 ,7.

Comment: Thankyou for the break warning but the empty and full cases are still not working. I changed 's1.isFull()==true' to just 's1.full()' same issue again.

Comment: Why do you need all of this code to simply test the empty and full functions?  Just put a single item in the stack, call the `isEmpty()`.  If it doesn't work, fix the code there.  Don't add superfluous and unnecessary things in the code like prompts, menus, and whatever else you have in the program.  We have to wade through 3 screensworth of code to see a simple test of those functions you have trouble with.

Comment: `for(int i;i<5;i++)` should be `for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)`. You might be writing `0` to `top` inadvertently because of this error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: you don't have to wade through anything; the OP is clearly new to C++ and trying to learn, be kind and helpful, else go elsewhere.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to use the debugger to single-step through your code and a each step check that the values are what you expect.

Comment: @slashmais *you don't have to wade through anything; the OP is clearly new to C++* -- The advice is to write the smallest test code to see if things are working *before* adding code that doesn't help.  Is that good enough or no?  Otherwise the OP will never learn *how* to ask or formulate future questions.

Comment: thankyou everyone and yes I am new to c++ sorry @PaulMcKenzie if this caused any trouble.

Comment: No it didn't cause trouble -- it's just that you need to learn how to incrementally write and test a program.  You spend a lot of time writing things like menus, prompts, etc.  but that took all of the time away from where it really is important -- getting the stack to work properly.  A lot of students make this mistake of using up precious time in getting pretty input and output, and totally leave off the important things, like getting the calculations or data structure(s) working correctly.   Then the time allotted to their project runs out and you get a bad grade, but nice looking output.

Comment: Update: I figured the problem here. I had no else statement for the if in my switch case. thankyou for all your inputs!